# Android studio [2.1] Does not display "Import class"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I used the android studio and maybe somehow removed the import function of the class that pops up when I press the alt + enter combination, now I can not import classes in this way, only prescribing them manually, tell me please how to fix it

How it should be and how it is now :
[image]

Comment: Are you not getting any kind of error or warning in .gradle files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should probably work:

Go to -> 'File' > 'Invalidate caches/restart'

Answer (score 0):

goto->build->clean project->rebuild project